# Adding CSS style into specific line HTML table

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need to check if my HTML table contains a specific string (for example 'LA DEFENSE') and then color the current line by adding `style="background-color: red"`

[image]

I would like something like :

```
$("#colorline").click(function() {
       if ($('rejets_communes').contains('LA DEFENSE'){
              #color line by adding style element to the specific line
        }
 })
```

Answer (score 3):

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/dm6u9jy5/) is a working fiddle.

```
<table id="myTable">
<tr>
  <td>LA DEFENSE</td>
  <td>SOMETHING ELSE</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

If you want to set the background color for the whole line you can use

```
$('#myTable').find("td:contains('LA DEFENSE')").parents("tr").css('background-color', 'red');
```

otherwise, use this

```
$('#myTable').find("td:contains('LA DEFENSE')").css('background-color', 'red');
```